# Grafana "grafana-meta-queries" not found

Tags: grafana

Hellow!

I need use this plugin in my grafana: https://github.com/GoshPosh/grafana-meta-queries
and I have configured in this way:

[image]

The error that I received is "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"
I am testing in a grafana 8.5.2 and in 8.4.5, the docker version

I dont know what I am doing bad

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if plugin is showing as signed? As it is mandatory for all plugins to be signed with Grafana version 8. Also, it would be great if you could share error with 'Query Inspector'. Do have proper datasource configured.

Comment: Thanks ritu... we decided stop to this stuff